# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DNUMBER in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\

Tags: php, php-parse-error

I have this error message on windows vps.

Complete error message:

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DNUMBER in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\kayahomesonline.com\httpdocs\configuration.php on line 24"

My configuration.php content is:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

session_start();

## Set the time for IST
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Istanbul');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'turkish');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'tr_TR.UTF-8');
// setlocale(LC_TIME, 'tr_TR');

$title = "KAYAHOMES YÖNETİM PANELİ";

$baseURL = "https://www.kayahomesonline.com";
$basePath = "C:\Inetpub\vhosts\kayahomesonline.com\httpdocs\";

## JavaScript General Path
$js_path = 'http://script.rezsis.com/js/';
$img_path = 'http://script.rezsis.com/images/';

$version = "0.1";

$baglan = mysql_connect('localhost','datauser','D4t4b4s3*');

if (!$baglan)
    {
        die('Veritabanına bağlanılamadı... Lütfen yetkilinizle irtibata geçin...' . mysql_error());
    }

mysql_select_db('kayahomes_new',$baglan) or header("Location: ../login.php");   
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");

?>
```

what is wrong? This config file is working on my old Linux VPS.

Comment: The last ``\`` in your `$basePath` string is escaping the `"`, so the string doesn't end there (as all the red color in the highlighter shows). You need a ``..\\";`` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @deceze pointed out the string is not ending here in the variable `$basePath`. You would need to add a backslash to make the string an end.

So the code would be like

```
$basePath = "C:\Inetpub\vhosts\kayahomesonline.com\httpdocs\\";
```